# Java - building a new members block

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Java Spring Boot and I am looking to create a set of admin dashboard components.

One is a "new members" in the last 28 days block.

[image]

So the user table will look something like this

```
id  |  email        |  password        | registeredDate
1   |  a@gmail.com  |  $2hasdhdahjasd  | 12/01/2017
2   |  b@gmail.com  |  $2hdsfdsfhgjsd  | 15/01/2017
3   |  c@gmail.com  |  $4sdfdggfdsfsd  | 17/01/2017
4   |  d@gmail.com  |  $6hasdfdahjasg  | 01/02/2017
5   |  e@gmail.com  |  $9fdfdfdahjasg  | 03/02/2017
6   |  f@gmail.com  |  $89dddfdahjasg  | 07/02/2017
7   |  g@gmail.com  |  $fghgdfdahjasg  | 07/02/2017
```

--
so in this instance - say its February - "4+25%"

What kind of algorithms/logic do I start with to get the correct data?

```
    // 28 days ago
    Calendar thresholdPast = Calendar.getInstance();
    thresholdPast.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    thresholdPast.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    thresholdPast.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    thresholdPast.add(Calendar.DATE,-28);
```

I am using a JPA to get the data out of the system - if there is a way of creating a line that will fetch these stats?

```
public interface TblLoginRepository extends JpaRepository<TblLogin, String> {
    long count();
    List<TblLogin> findAll();
}
```

Comment: `long countByRegisteredDateAfter`? (And if you're using Hibernate 5, you can use `LocalDate` or `Instant`.)

Comment: Is this the JPA? -- so create one called "long countByRegisteredDateAfter(Date thresholdDate)"   --- so in the Java code -- get -- Integer count =  tblLoginRepository.countByRegisteredDateAfter(thresholdDate);

Comment: That's a Spring Data query. If you put it on your repository, Spring Data will create the JPA query for you.

Comment: I see - so then the difference between the increase/decrease -- comes from getting the threshold value -- and then thresholdx2 value so one is 28 days - the other 56 days -- and then assess the percentage increase of decrease?